# How to create a rate column in sql?

Tags: sql, databricks

I'm using this query:

```
select 
company_type, year_month, months_since_first_date, count(distinct entitlement_id) as number_of_ids
from t1
group by company_type, year_month, months_since_first_date 
order by year_month, months_since_first_date
```

This is the table I get:

```
| company_type | year_month | months_since_first_date | number_of_ids |
| -----------    -----------  -----------------------   ------------- |
| Small          2022-01                 1                    100     |
| Medium         2022-01                 1                     50     |
| Large          2022-01                 1                     50     |
| Small          2022-01                 2                    100     |
| Medium         2022-01                 2                     80     |
| Large          2022-01                 2                     20     |
```

I'm trying to create another column that will calculate the rate of ids as time passes. Here's an example:

```
| company_type | year_month | months_since_first_date | number_of_ids | rate |
| -----------    -----------  -----------------------   ------------- | -----
| Small          2022-01                 1                    100     | 50   |
| Medium         2022-01                 1                     50     | 25   |
| Large          2022-01                 1                     50     | 25   |
| Small          2022-01                 2                    100     | 50   |
| Medium         2022-01                 2                     80     | 40   |
| Large          2022-01                 2                     20     | 10   |
```

How can I do that? I'm been experimenting with over() and partition by() but it's not working. This is what I'm trying to use:

```
count(id) * 100 / count(count(id) over() as rate
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
select 
company_type, year_month, months_since_first_date, count(distinct entitlement_id) as number_of_ids, number_of_ids / 2 AS rate
from t1
group by company_type, year_month, months_since_first_date 
order by year_month, months_since_first_date
```

Note :
Looking at your expected results, I have considered that you want the result number_of_ids divided by 2 in the rate column.

Answer (score 0):

Use Sum() Over() analytic function to calculate percentage...

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    your_data (COMPANY_TYPE, YEAR_MONTH, MONTHS_SINCE_FIRST_DATE, NUMBER_OF_IDS) AS
        ( Select 'Small',  '2022-01', 1, 100 From Dual Union All
          Select 'Medium', '2022-01', 1,  50 From Dual Union All
          Select 'Large',  '2022-01', 1,  50 From Dual Union All
          Select 'Small',  '2022-01', 2, 100 From Dual Union All
          Select 'Medium', '2022-01', 2,  80 From Dual Union All
          Select 'Large',  '2022-01', 2,  20 From Dual 
        )
```

```sql
--     S Q L :
Select  COMPANY_TYPE, YEAR_MONTH, MONTHS_SINCE_FIRST_DATE, NUMBER_OF_IDS,
        NUMBER_OF_IDS * 100 / Sum(NUMBER_OF_IDS) Over(Partition By MONTHS_SINCE_FIRST_DATE) as RATE
From      your_data
```

```sql
/*      R e s u l t :
COMPANY_TYPE YEAR_MO MONTHS_SINCE_FIRST_DATE NUMBER_OF_IDS       RATE
------------ ------- ----------------------- ------------- ----------
Small        2022-01                       1           100         50
Medium       2022-01                       1            50         25
Large        2022-01                       1            50         25
Small        2022-01                       2           100         50
Medium       2022-01                       2            80         40
Large        2022-01                       2            20         10   */
```